# SOA. What's exactly the enterprise components and how it reflects services?

Tags: soa, visio, diagrams

I have been trying to draw SOA layers diagram with Visio 2013, but cannot figure out the "Service Components" naming convention. How components should be named deeply in details? Should it be named technically?

Consider this:

**Service layer:**  car information search

**Operations:** get car information by code, get car information by holder, etc

**Service components:** How to name it???

**If someone can upload exact real world example of SOA layers, it will be the most helpful thing**

It's hard to relate all layers to interact each other, i cannot find any real example of SOA layers diagram...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information on the classification you're using. Is this the open group SOA RA? A picture of the diagram might also be of help.

Comment: @PlamenPetrov yes it's Open Group layered architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found in terms of real-life sample:

[Click for high resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFFTl.png)

[image: SOA RA sample]

It is from [this](http://www.slideshare.net/afattah2/enterprise-reference-architecture-v11ppt) presentation.

The description of the service component layer according to SOA RA by the open group, you can [read in detail here](https://www.opengroup.org/soa/source-book/soa_refarch/servcomp.htm). As I look at the architecture building blocks of this layer it seems to hold the underlying functionality/logic that enables the service to act accordingly to its contract (which is defined in the Services layer). So in your case probably you will have a `Search Manager` or `Data Manager` or `Car Search Manager` as a service component.

Note that most of the components in this layer are quite technical and are used in the realization of  multiple services (e.g. Service Invoker, Service Publisher, etc.), so it makes sense to name them in a more general way (not just in the context of one service). I suggest that you dont't even include these in the diagram explicitly, unless your aim is going into great technical details.

Comment: Thank you, i have already did it. I wonder, if there is any specific tools/diagrams for SOA layered architecture? When i was drawing a diagram, i got some problems with layers "relations": system has a lot of services and components, so connecting both layers rised a lot of connectors' overlaps and distortions. Btw, your answer proved that I did it right. Thanks again!

Comment: This problem (with the many connections) you'll have with other software as well as with Visio. Big diagrams tend to get messy. Try to rearranging the connections manually, try without snap & glue, etc.  Anyway, you're welcome - I'm glad I did help, even though a bit late.